# Serialize to XML an object that contains IList

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

So I have an Object called FormType.
It contains some strings, booleans etc.

But FormType also contains this:

```
   private IList<FormTypeVersion> _versions = new List<FormTypeVersion>();

    public virtual IList<FormTypeVersion> Versions
    {
        get { return _versions; }
        set { _versions = value; }
    }
```

Is this why I am getting this error:

```
{"Cannot serialize member 'Domain.FormType.Versions' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
```

Also - FormTypeVersion also contains some ILists.

How can I get round this error, it happens at this line:

```
var xm = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` cannot deserialize interfaces (unless you want to implement IXmlSerializable yourself on the FormType object). That is why you are seeing that exception.

If you change your IList to **List** it should work like in the following example:

```
[Serializable]
public class FormType
{
    private List<FormTypeVersion> _versions = new List<FormTypeVersion>();

    public virtual List<FormTypeVersion> Versions
    {
        get { return _versions; }
        set { _versions = value; }
    }
}
```

If you don't have the luxury to change your type from IList to List, then the cleanest approach is to implement `IXmlSerializable`. There are other solutions using abstract types, reflection and similar, but i wouldn't call that clean.

Comment: will try this but not sure this will be acceptable - why are they defined as IList in the first place?

Comment: That is not a question for me :) ask whoever implemented the FormType class. There are many reason to use or not use an interface in code, that is a very broad question.